# When does the improper integral converge?

Tags: integration

For positive numbers $p$ and $q$, find the condition for $p$ and $q$ such that the integral
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^p(1+x)^q}$$
converge.

$x^p < (1+x)^p \Rightarrow x^p (1+x)^q < (1+x)^{p+q}$, and I'm stuck...

Comment: Letting $t=\dfrac1{1+x}$ this becomes the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 4):

We should study the problems of the convergence at $0$ and at $\infty$:

- We have

$$\frac{1}{x^p(1+x)^q}\sim_0\frac1{x^p}$$
and we know that

$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^p}\;\text{exists}\iff p<1$$

- We have
  $$\frac{1}{x^p(1+x)^q}\sim_\infty\frac1{x^{p+q}}$$
  and

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{p+q}}\;\text{exists}\iff p+q>1$$
so the given integral exists if and only if
$$(p<1)\land (p+q>1)$$

Comment: How can we conclude like that..? First what does ~0 and ~ inf mean??